# Matching varients and mis-spellings of a word using RegEx in MS Word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture varients of a word using Microsft Word find and replace function. Here is a searchable snippet:

```
       There are going to be 3 instances of the word successful for the purpose of Regex matching. Here is the second sucesfull and here is another succesfull , both spelt incorrectly.
```

This is my Regex expression used in Find and Replace with "Use Wildcards" selected (I have also tried this with replacing the braces with brackets with no joy)

<([Ss]uc[1,]es[1,]ful[1,])>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Ss]uc{1,}es{1,}ful{1,}
```

Replace the [ ] with { } and it should work fine. The curly braces specify how many times you want a character to repeat. Square brackets are used to specify the acceptable characters.

So the current regular expression will match the following.

- succcccesssfulll
- sucesful
- successful
- Successsssfull

and so on.

I think this is cleaner and easier to type.

```
[Ss]uc+es+ful+
```

"+" counts for one or more occurrence of a character.

Answer (score 0):

The search string you want would be:

```
<[sS]uc@es@ful@>
```

This searches for a word (the `<` and `>` symbols) starting with either `s` or `S` and including one or more (the `@` symbol) of `c`, `s`, and `l`.